# Hbase client does not connect to local hbase server

Tags: java, hadoop, intellij-idea, hbase, bigdata

I am attempting to run simple Hbase client program which talks to Hbase server(standalone) to create a table and a single row.  However, unfortunately am seeing following exception while running through intelliJ.

```
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
Initializing HBaseAdmin
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.hadoop.security.Groups).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
Hbase running, Creating table
Adding data into table
Exception in thread "main"  org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RetriesExhaustedWithDetailsException: Failed 1 action: User: 1 time, 
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.AsyncProcess$BatchErrors.makeException(AsyncProcess.java:205)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.AsyncProcess$BatchErrors.access$500(AsyncProcess.java:189)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.AsyncProcess.getErrors(AsyncProcess.java:1042)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable.backgroundFlushCommits(HTable.java:1037)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable.flushCommits(HTable.java:1352)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable.put(HTable.java:963)
at HbaseSample.main(HbaseSample.java:22)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:134)
Done
```

Client Program:

```
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HBaseConfiguration;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HBaseAdmin;

import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.*;

public class HbaseSample {
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("Initializing HBaseAdmin");
    Configuration conf = HBaseConfiguration.create();
    conf.set("hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort","2181");
    conf.set("hbase.master", "localhost:60000");
    HBaseAdmin admin = new HBaseAdmin(conf);
    try {
        HBaseAdmin.checkHBaseAvailable(conf);
        System.out.println("Hbase running, Creating table");
        HTable table = new HTable(conf, "User");
        Put put = new Put(Bytes.toBytes("msameer"));
        put.add(Bytes.toBytes("Info"), Bytes.toBytes("addr"), Bytes.toBytes("walnut creek"));
        System.out.println("Adding data into table");
        table.put(put);
    } finally {
        admin.close();
        System.out.println("Done");
    }
  }
}
```

My hbase-site.xml looks as follows:

```
<configuration>
<property>
  <name>hbase.rootdir</name>
  <value>file:///Users/msameer/Documents/Hbase/hbase-root</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>hbase.zookeeper.property.dataDir</name>
  <value>/Users/msameer/Documents/Hbase/hbase-zookeper</value>
</property>
<property>
   <name>hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort</name>
   <value>2181</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>hbase.master</name>
  <value>localhost:60000</value>
</property>
</configuration>
```

Any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: what version of hbase?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Does your table already exist?  Because this code does not create a table:

```
HBaseAdmin.checkHBaseAvailable(conf);
System.out.println("Hbase running, Creating table");
HTable table = new HTable(conf, "User");
```

This will only use a table that already exists.  To create a table, you need to use `HBaseAdmin`:

```
HBaseAdmin.checkHBaseAvailable(conf);
System.out.println("Hbase running, Creating table");
HTableDescriptor des = new HTableDescriptor("User");
HBaseAdmin.createTable(des);
```

Take a look at the [documentation](http://hbase.apache.org/book.html#schema.creation) for schema creation.  It also shows the updated API calls.  The classes starting with `H` are now deprecated.

Comment: Thanks very much Martin, yes the table was not created. Also, thanks for pointing to the right api docs.

Comment: your welcome.  note you can also upvote the answer if you like.

Comment: He don't have enough reputation to up vote. I agree that your answer is useful.

Comment: I will be sure to up vote once I have enough reputation. Just starting off on stack overflow.